# Campo calculado em Java

Tags: java, sql

Eu estou a fazer um projeto em Java e tenho uma base de dado com duas tabelas e uma delas com um campo calculado.

O campo calculado é do tipo "time" e foi feito com o comando

```
UPDATE nome_da_tabela SET Nome_do_campo = TIMEDIFF(hora2, hora1)
```

Eu tenho dois prepared statements em Java: um para inserir e outro para fazer o campo calculado, ou seja, o Update.

Agora, quando eu vou inserir um registo, em Java, na tabela que tem o campo calculado e não insere na base de dados. Dá um erro a dizer:

> "Field 'Nome_do_campo' doesn't have a default value"

Comment: Talvez se você recriar o seu campo na tabela, da uma olhada nesses links do MySQL: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/data-type-defaults.html e https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/timestamp-initialization.html

Comment: update sem o where ? é para atualizar em todos os registros da tabela mesmo ? acredito que nessa coluna na hora do seu insert, você deva informar `null` , ou mesmo já efetuar o calculo na hora do insert... `INSERT INTO .... (coluna_dif, ...) VALUES (TIMEDIFF(hora2, hora1), ... );`

Comment: update sem where, sei bem o que isso pode acarretar. Tenho um banco com 1850 letras de musicas nas versões italiana, espanhola, inglesa e brasileira totalizando 7400 letras. Certa vez fui atualizar uma letra de uma musica e fiz assim: UPDATE all_pages_ordernada SET letra='".$letra_br."'); O resto vc já sabe né. Muito cuidado com esses esquecimentos!!!

Comment: o que me parece, ele executa esse 'calculo' a cada insert... desnecessário

Comment: @RovannLinhalis é para atualizar após o `INSERT` nessa tabela. Também posso fazer um `PreparedStatement`no Java com o comando `INSERT INTO..VALUES(TIMEDIFF(hora1, hora2....)`

Comment: exatamente... após a cada INSERT você executa um update, na mesma tabela ? me parece desnecessário